# Saving player inventory

Tags: java, bukkit

Working on a command allowing to transfer worlds, I'm trying to save the player inventory.

```
public void savePlayerInv(Player p, World w){
    File playerInvConfigFile = new File(plugin.getDataFolder() + File.separator + "players" + File.separator + p.getName(), "inventory.yml");
    FileConfiguration pInv = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(playerInvConfigFile);
    PlayerInventory inv = p.getInventory();
    int i = 0;

    for (ItemStack stack : inv.getContents()) {
        //increment integer
        i++;
        String startInventory = w.getName() + ".inv." + Integer.toString(i);

        //save inv
        pInv.set(startInventory + ".amount", stack.getAmount());
        pInv.set(startInventory + ".durability", Short.toString(stack.getDurability()));
        pInv.set(startInventory + ".type", stack.getTypeId());
        //pInv.set(startInventory + ".enchantment", stack.getEnchantments());
        //TODO add enchant saveing
    }

    i = 0;
    for (ItemStack armor : inv.getArmorContents()){
            i++;
            String startArmor = w.getName() + ".armor." + Integer.toString(i);

            //save armor
            pInv.set(startArmor + ".amount", armor.getAmount());
            pInv.set(startArmor + ".durability", armor.getDurability());
            pInv.set(startArmor + ".type", armor.getTypeId());
            //pInv.set(startArmor + ".enchantment", armor.getEnchantments());
    }

    //save exp
    if (p.getExp() != 0) {
            pInv.set(w.getName() + ".exp", p.getExp());
    }
}
```

The problem is on line 130:

```
pInv.set(startInventory + ".amount", stack.getAmount());
```

I get this stacktrace:

```
2012-03-21 13:23:25 [SEVERE] null
org.bukkit.command.CommandException: Unhandled exception executing command 'wtp' in plugin Needs v1.0
at org.bukkit.command.PluginCommand.execute(PluginCommand.java:42)
at org.bukkit.command.SimpleCommandMap.dispatch(SimpleCommandMap.java:166)
at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.CraftServer.dispatchCommand(CraftServer.java:461)
at net.minecraft.server.NetServerHandler.handleCommand(NetServerHandler.java:818)
at net.minecraft.server.NetServerHandler.chat(NetServerHandler.java:778)
at net.minecraft.server.NetServerHandler.a(NetServerHandler.java:761)
at net.minecraft.server.Packet3Chat.handle(Packet3Chat.java:33)
at net.minecraft.server.NetworkManager.b(NetworkManager.java:229)
at net.minecraft.server.NetServerHandler.a(NetServerHandler.java:112)
at net.minecraft.server.NetworkListenThread.a(NetworkListenThread.java:78)
at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.w(MinecraftServer.java:554)
at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:452)
at net.minecraft.server.ThreadServerApplication.run(SourceFile:490)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.devoverflow.improved.needs.commands.CommandWorldtp.savePlayerInv(CommandWorldtp.java:130)
at com.devoverflow.improved.needs.commands.CommandWorldtp.onCommand(CommandWorldtp.java:60)
at org.bukkit.command.PluginCommand.execute(PluginCommand.java:40)
... 12 more
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do `inv.getContents()`, you retrieve every slot in the player inventory, including the empty slots.
These empty slots return `null` because there is nothing in them.

To fix, add an if statement right after you start the for loop:

```
for (ItemStack stack : inv.getContents()) {
    if (stack == null) continue;
    // And keep everything else the same
}
```

The problem you might encounter later would be replacing everything in the exact same slot it came from.
I suggest using a `HashMap` or something to keep track of which slot the item came from.